# Using HTML color tag in json

Tags: android, html, json

I have problem with using color html tag in my json text

```
{
  "name":"john",
  "dsc":"<p>hello <span style="color: #ff0000;">people</span>, <strong>how</strong> are you</p>"
}
```

json editor does not recognize this code as valid JSON, how can I add html text with color to my json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the string is wrapped in double quotes `"`, you must either escape the double quotes inside the string (by prepending a backslash `\`), or use singles quotes `'`, which is also acceptable JSON syntax.

Escaped double quotes:

```
{
    "name": "john", 
    "dsc": "<p>hello <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">people</span>, <strong>how</strong> are you</p>"
}
```

Single quotes:

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "dsc": "<p>hello <span style='color: #ff0000;'>people</span>, <strong>how</strong> are you</p>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple and it correctly escapes this line

Sample

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("name", "john");
    jsonObject.put("dsc", "<p>hello <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">people</span>, <strong>how</strong> are you</p>");

    System.err.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());
    System.err.println(jsonObject.get("name").toString());
    System.err.println(jsonObject.get("dsc").toString());
```

Result

```
    {
        "name":"john",
        "dsc":"<p>hello <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">people<\/span>, <strong>how<\/strong> are you<\/p>"
    }
    john
    <p>hello <span style="color: #ff0000;">people</span>, <strong>how</strong> are you</p>
```